# How To Do OpenSCAD Stack-Like Operations?

Tags: stack, openscad

I'm pretty new to OpenSCAD, but have got most of it down. However, I'm not sure how I can do stack-like operations. It doesn't really matter what data structure is used, as long as I can push and pop numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I'm trying to make an OpenSCAD program that will generate a maze using a recursive backtracker method. Part of the recursive backtracker algorithm involves storing the coordinates an explorer object 'moves' through. When the explorer reaches a dead end, it goes the the last coordinate stored. In stack terms, it pushes coordinates to the stack, then pops them off when it gets stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I worked extensively with stacks while implementing a [string processing library](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:526023).

The trick is to use nested right associative lists of size = 2, e.g. ["foo", ["bar", []]].

If you want to push something to a stack:

```
function push(stack, item) = [item, stack];
```

If you want to pop the stack:

```
function pop(stack) = stack[1];
```

And if you want to peek or retrieve the value that was popped:

```
function peek(stack) = stack[0];
```

You can also implement map/reduce functions using recursion:

```
function map(stack) = 
    push(
         map(pop(stack)),  
         f(peek(stack)) 
    );

function reduce(stack) = 
    f(peek(stack))? 
        push(
             reduce(pop(stack)),
             f(peek(stack))
        ) 
    : 
        reduce(pop(stack))
    ;
```

Of course, now that version 2015.03 is out you might consider using list comprehension, assuming that's what you really need.